# How to make 123 become 122333

Tags: c

Please tell me how to print num in the same form as 122333 when num = 123 is entered in c.
I can make a repetition of a number separately, but I can't print it out by adding it to num.

Comment: Lazy Way: `sprintf` and `atoi`.

Comment: Please be more precise in your description.  If the input is `147`, should that be converted to `144777` or `144447777777` or something else entirely?

Comment: You could simply do `if( num == 123 ) puts("122333"); else fprintf(stderr, "invalid input\n");`

Answer (score 0):

you can get the number of digits first in your desired number, then you can get digit by digit from the left using the equation `digit = num / (10^(numOfDigits)) % 10` where `numOfDigits` is just a variable used to indicate which digit to extract right now.

so when you get digit by digit you can use `for-loop` to loop `digit` times on that digit to be printed.

so you can do something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    int num = 123;
    int numOfDigits = 0;
    int dummy = num;

    // finding number of digits
    while (dummy != 0)
    {
        // increment number of digits
        numOfDigits++;

        // go to next digit
        dummy /= 10;
    }

    printf("output = ");
    while (numOfDigits != 0){

        // get the current digit
        int digit = (num / (int)pow(10,(numOfDigits-1))) % 10;

        for (int i = 0; i < digit; ++i) {
            // print the number
            printf("%d", digit);
        }

        // go to next digit
        numOfDigits--;
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

and this is the output:

```
output = 122333
```